# bind event on generated element and get its current state

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, closures, jquery

Here is a plug-in that binds a `click` event on an element, which generates a container with a `<textarea>` and  then i bind a `keypress` event on this new `<textarea>`, all is ok, but inside the `keypress` handler i can only get the state of `text().length` from when the initial `click` happened.

How do i get the onKeyPress function to get the state of the  `<textarea>` at the time the `keypress` happened?

```
$.fn.pluginTemp = function(options){
    var defaults = {
            editContainer:"<div class='editContainer'><textarea></textarea></div>",
            maxChar:20,
            onKeyPress:function(){
                    console.log($(".editContainer>textarea").text())
               }

     }
    var options = $.extend(defaults,options); 
    return this.each(function(i,e){
        var el = $(e), initText
        el.bind("click", function(){
            initText = el.text();
            el.parent().append(options.editContainer);
            el.parent().find(".editContainer>textarea").html(initText);
              // isn't this function remembering the state for when its is defined?  which is on keypress?          
               return function(){
                el.parent().find(".editContainer>textarea").bind("keypress",options.onKeyPress)
            }()

        })
    })
}
```

Comment: You might want to check the .live() method - http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: `live` on the keypress? also, isnt there a way i can do this with a closure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem,

Instead of getting the current value via the `.html()` method,
I used `.val()`

Here is why:
The `.html()` method when used on a `<textarea>` looks only at the initial state of the `textarea`, When you have `.val()` it samples the most current value.

Comment: If you'd used .live() you'd get the same result because the function is executed at the time the event is triggered. So in other words, having it on the keypress event would have generated the html at that time. But hey, .val() works too and is much simpler :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
return this.each(function(i,e){
            var el = $(e), initText
            el.live('click', function() {
                initText = el.text();
                el.parent().append(options.editContainer);
                el.parent().find(".editContainer>textarea").html(initText);
                  // isn't this function remembering the state for when its is defined?  which is on keypress?          
                   return function(){
                    el.parent().find(".editContainer>textarea").bind("keypress",options.onKeyPress)
                }()

            })
        })
```

Haven't tested as yet sorry